# How to enable .zip file download in a directory inside wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, download, zip

I have created a wordpress website. I have created a directory named *my-resources* in the root directory & uploaded few zip files to it via FTP. Now I am trying to download the zip files by directly entering the zip file URL in a browser but it is always showing the wordpress default 404 page. I tried to enable using .htaccess without any success.

Example URL: http://www.example.com/my-resources/sample.zip

Additional Notes:

1. Its a Linux Server
2. I have configured permalinks like http://www.example.com/sample-post/
3. I have installed *Easy Media Download*, *Yoast SEO* plugins which I think might conflict with the file download

How do I enable to download zip files from a particular directory?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chmod command and give permission 755 to that downloadable directory. You can use help of command from this link
http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: HI, I did the same but no success yet. Anyways, thanks for your response